# make mosquitto-auth-plug on windows

Tags: authentication, plugins, mqtt, mosquitto

I am currently trying to build the mosquitto-auth-plugin on windows but I am unsure which make process to use.  The doc says to edit the config.mk file which I have done, then to 'make' the auth-plug -- this is were I am struck I have tried to make using GnWin & MinGW but neither has worked is there a way to build-make the library on windows or can I make it in Linux and copy the auth-plug.o to my windows machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of anybody having attempted to build `mosquitto-auth-plug` on Windows, and I'd be very surprised if that worked at all; as the author of the plugin, I paid no attention to portability outside Un*x, and so as to not raise hopes, I will not. :-)

That said, you cannot run (load) shared objects built on Linux on Windows. What may be possible, but it's been years since I did anything similar, is to cross compile with an appropriate toolchain.

Comment: thanks for the reply - but just to be clear can I use this plugin if my mosquitto broker is running on a windows machine?

Comment: The short answer is nobody has ever tried to use the plugin on Windows. As such, I would say no, you can not currently use it if you want to run your broker on Windows

Comment: The answer, currently, is a definitive No, you cannot use the plugin on your Mosquitto broker on Windows as @hardlib says. The only alternative I can think of, is to run Linux on a virtual machine on Windows and run Mosquitto in that, but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I build it for Windows, using the HTTP and JWT backends only.

Had to fix:

1. Put __declspec(dllexport) to the mosquitto_auth_Xyz... functions in auth-plug.c.
2. Added alternative code for fnmatch(a,b) and strsep() in auth-plug.c, see below.
3. In log.c I fell back to use log=__log instead of log=mosquitto_log_printf as I failed importing the function from libmosquitto.
4. Compiled using Visual Studio 2017 Express with preprocessor definitions _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE and _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS put into place.

The code works fine!

For fnmatch(a,b) and strsep() in auth-plug.c change the #include  to:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#define fnmatch(a, b, c) PathMatchSpecA(a, b)
extern char* strsep(char** stringp, const char* delim)
{
    char* start = *stringp;
    char* p;

    p = (start != NULL) ? strpbrk(start, delim) : NULL;

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        *stringp = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        *p = '\0';
        *stringp = p + 1;
    }

    return start;
}
#else
#include <fnmatch.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Could you share a github repo of this @Thomas?

Comment: Not sure I got it around somewhere, but will take a look for you. In the meantime you might consider if https://github.com/bluerange-io/bluerange-mosquitto/tree/master/auth is a suitable alternative. It is more performant as it fetches an acl at logon time only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thomas, don't think that repo run on Windows though right?

Comment: Hm, true it Lacks the dllexports as well. The setup of the auth-plug I had years ago is not available anymore as that pc was disposed last year.

Comment: You might consider giving the instructions above a try.