# Mosquitto reload config file

Tags: windows, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to reload the mosquitto password file when it is changed. 
Is possible to send SIGHUP ("signal hang up") or some equivalent to mosquitto server on windows?

Comment: You'll be able to do this in version 1.5: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/pull/163

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do so. First you have to set your ***mosquitto.conf*** to save the pid in a file by specifying the pid_file.

```
pid_file your/pid/file
```

Then you can call

```
$kill -SIGHUP $(cat your/pid/file).
```

Or else if you already know the PID of the mosquitoo, then you can do

```
$kill -SIGHUP PID
```

This will send sighup signal and reload the pwfile. More info can be found at [mosquitto conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/mosquitto.conf.5.html)

Comment: As reference for reloaded and not reloaded parameters on `SIGHUP` signal, check this document: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.5.en.html#GENERAL_OPTIONS

Comment: Of course, the pid file will not be reloaded.
That is used for store the PID of the process.
What we need is to get running PID of the process and reload the required configurations (which will be reload from other config files).

Comment: What we needs to reload is the password_file which will be reloaded at the Reload Signal

Comment: The question specifically asks for Windows.  This is for Linux so does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Since I found this thread looking for an answer on Linux I think this reply is relevant for some.

I think I found a simplified version of dulaj's answer (for Linux).  If you look at /etc/init.d/mosquitto (found on Mosquitto v.31) you'll see there is a "reload" option which has adds "--signal HUP" to the start-stop-daemon and it listed as "Reloading network daemon configuration: mosquitto".

So you should be able to run "sudo service mosquitto reload"

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.5 of Mosquitto, you can signal the named event `mosq<pid>_reload` ([the relevant code change](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/pull/163/commits/e83634da8cb6e503d5c0eb7cc02afffeb8a2ecb0)).

Sample code:

```
auto h = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, "mosq0000_reload");
SetEvent(h);
```

Example to get the pid in Windows can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, but you could use the [mosquitto-auth-plugin](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) which allows you to keep the ACL in a database that you can update while mosquitto is running.

This lets you a range of different database backends and you can add, remove, change ACL and users on the fly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808612/make-mosquitto-auth-plug-on-windows @jpmens says "No, you cannot use the plugin on your Mosquitto broker on Windows "

Comment: Doh, forgot about that. I'm sure he will accept pull requests to get it to build on windows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have .NET Framework installed, which comes by default in newer versions of Windows, Mosquitto settings can be reloaded through a PowerShell script that publishes a named event. This way you don't need to go deep into the Windows API to notify Mosquitto.

First you have to set your `mosquitto.conf` to save the pid in a file by specifying the `pid_file`.

Then, you just need to run this PowerShell script:

```
$mosquittoPid = cat "mosquitto.pid"
$handle = [System.Threading.EventWaitHandle]::new($false, [System.Threading.EventResetMode]::ManualReset, "mosq${mosquittoPid}_reload")
$handle.Set()
$handle.Dispose()
```

As previously mentioned by @dlanod, this only works on versions 1.5 or higher.