# Adding Users in MQTT Broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have an MQTT broker running in Ubuntu 16.04. My question is that how I can add users while the broker is running? When I add a user using

```
mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquito/pwfile user2
```

The user does show up in pwfile but I am not able to access that user from an external source until I restart the broker.
I have tried to use

```
sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

to reload the mosquitto.conf file but it gives this error

```
1483102542: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1483102542: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1483102542: Error: Address already in use
```

So what should I do to add users to broker and load them without restarting the broker?(I am using ESP8266 devices to access this broker and I have also tried to access the newly added user using MQTTLens(a chrome extension) but I was unable to access)

Answer (score 11):

There are 2 options for this.

1. Mosquitto reads the password file when it starts so will not pick up the changes when you run `mosquitto_passwd`. You can force mosquitto to re-read the file by sending the mosquitto broker a HUP signal
2. The better option is to stop using the password file if you are going to add/remove users dynamically and use the [mosquitto-auth-plugin](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug#postgresql) which lets you use a database to store the usernames/passwords and the ACL entries.

Comment: Just be aware (according to the doco link in 2 above), "Topic wildcards (+/#) are not supported". Not sure if anyone has found a way to make them work. Otherwise good idea, have it in a db to manage it :)

Comment: @Trevor wildcards are supported, just not with the Redis backend

Comment: Note [mosquitto-auth-plugin](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) is deprecated and Mosquitto v2 introduced [Dynamic Security Plugin](https://mosquitto.org/documentation/dynamic-security) which could be another option

Answer (score 3):

You can Reload the configuration without interrupting the existing connections by sending ***SIGHUP*** to the process.

```
$kill -SIGHUP PID
```

This will reload the pwfile. But not the PID file. More information of the reloading files with **HUP** can be found in : [mosquitto conf documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/mosquitto/man/mosquitto-conf-5.php)

Complete Steps are shown here: [reload mosquito config without restarting the service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42241657/2875999)

Comment: This answer is pretty much exactly the same as part 1 of my answer